# Else if loop command depending on result string

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I am trying to have a script take an argument and run a command against it and retry the command if a result matches a certain string. Otherwise other results will echo the result.

We have a script at work where we run `"rm <filename>"` but it takes 5 seconds to return whether successful or not and I want to make a script to keep running it until it sees a "destroyed file" string in the result.

This is what I have so far..

```
#!/bin/bash

function rm () {

if [[ $(rm $1 | grep -m 1 'destroyed file') ]]  ; then
        echo "Destroyed File"
elif [[ $(rm $1 | grep -m 1 'remove failed') ]] ; then
        sleep 5;
        rm $1
elif [[ $(rm $1 | grep -m 1 'not found') ]] ; then
        echo "file not found"
elif [[ $(rm $1 | grep -m 1 'You must have root access') ]] ; then
        echo "You do not have root access"
else
        echo "Incorrect parameter or command"
fi
}
```

Comment: Where's the loop?

Comment: Have you noticed your function is called `rm` and this matches the name of a command in `/bin`? -- your function is recursive.

Comment: Even if it weren't recursive, you are attempting to remove an already removed file each time the standard error doesn't match your most recent check.

Comment: The name of the function is one problem, but I would strongly suggest you avoid using "grep" for this, exit codes exist for this reason.

Comment: How is the external `rm` implemented? What `rm` outputs "destroyed file"?

Comment: In general, if you want to test the result of `grep`, check its return value rather than its output.  That is: `if [ rm "$1" | grep -m 1 'destroyed file' ]; then ...`  Also, this prints the output for you so you can skip the redundant `echo`.  (Use `grep -q` if you want to suppress the output.)

Comment: In addition to what the others already have said: In case you really manage to invoke /usr/bin/rm (what your programm currently does not do), the error message which is generated in case of the missing file, goes to stderr, but you are grepping stdout.